# How can I insert the saved data inside a custom list view from android Room?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-room

This might be a little confusing, majorly because this is my first app, and I have never done anything like this before. So please pardon me if I made some silly mistake.
I am working on a tasks app, in which, I have taken some data from the user [task name(string), priority(string) and time(string)] I have attempted to save this data into room. Now, on a different activity, I have a list view, on which I wish to put that saved data inside. I created a custom list item (since the priority and time are to be displayed as image views) and also an adapter class for it. However, I am lost on how I can call upon that saved data and put it into my list view for the user to see. This is all the code that might be relevant :

where I save the data in room :

```
package com.example.taskmasterv3;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.room.Dao;
import androidx.room.Database;
import androidx.room.Delete;
import androidx.room.Entity;
import androidx.room.Insert;
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey;
import androidx.room.Query;
import androidx.room.Room;
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SubtaskActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText etSubtaskName;
    EditText etTaskName;
    Button btnDone, btnCancel;
    RadioGroup radgrpPri, radgrpTime;
    RadioButton radbtnPriHigh, radbtnPriMed, radbtnPriLow, radbtnTimeMore, radbtnTimeMed, radbtnTimeLess;
    boolean priHigh, priMed, priLow, timeMore, timeMed, timeLess;
    String subtaskName;
    String pri;
    String time;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_subtask);

        btnDone = findViewById(R.id.btnDone);
        radgrpPri = findViewById(R.id.radgrpPri);
        radgrpTime = findViewById(R.id.radgrpTime);
        radbtnPriHigh = findViewById(R.id.radbtnPriHigh);
        radbtnPriMed = findViewById(R.id.radbtnPriMed);
        radbtnPriLow = findViewById(R.id.radbtnPriLow);
        radbtnTimeMore = findViewById(R.id.radbtnTimeMore);
        radbtnTimeMed = findViewById(R.id.radbtnTimeMed);
        radbtnTimeLess = findViewById(R.id.radbtnTimeLess);
        etSubtaskName = findViewById(R.id.etSubtaskName);
        btnCancel = findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);





        radgrpPri.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

                if (radbtnPriHigh.isChecked())
                {
                    priHigh = true;
                    priLow = false;
                    priMed = false;
                    pri = "h";




                }
                else if (radbtnPriMed.isChecked())
                {
                    priHigh = false;
                    priLow = false;
                    priMed = true;
                    pri = "m";


                }
                else if (radbtnPriLow.isChecked())
                {
                    priHigh = false;
                    priLow = true;
                    priMed = false;
                    pri = "l";
                }
                else {
                    priLow = true;
                    pri = "l";

                }

            }
        });

        radgrpTime.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

                if (radbtnTimeMore.isChecked())
                {
                    timeMore = true;
                    timeMed = false;
                    timeLess = false;

                    time = "more";
                }
               else if (radbtnTimeMed.isChecked())
                {
                    timeMore = false;
                    timeMed = true;
                    timeLess = false;
                    time = "med";
                }
               else if (radbtnTimeLess.isChecked())
                {
                    timeMore = false;
                    timeMed = false;
                    timeLess = true;
                    time = "less";
                }
               else
                {
                    timeLess = true;
                    time = "less";
                }

            }
        });






        btnDone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {




               String name = etSubtaskName.getText().toString().trim();

               Intent intent = new Intent(SubtaskActivity.this, TaskInfo.class);
               intent.putExtra("subtaskName", name);
               intent.putExtra("priHigh", priHigh);
               intent.putExtra("priMed", priMed);
               intent.putExtra("priLow", priLow);
               intent.putExtra("timeMore", timeMore);
               intent.putExtra("timeMed", timeMed);
               intent.putExtra("timeLess", timeLess);
               setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
               SubtaskActivity.this.finish();

               // THIS IS WHERE I SAVE THE DATA IN ROOM

                AppDatabase.databaseWriteExecutor.execute(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        SubtaskDetails subtaskDetails = new SubtaskDetails(etSubtaskName.toString().trim(), pri, time);
                        AppDatabase.getDatabase(getApplicationContext()).userDao().insertAll(subtaskDetails);

                    }
                });


            }
        });



        btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                etSubtaskName.setText("");
                radgrpPri.clearCheck();
                radgrpTime.clearCheck();
                finish();



            }
        });






    }

}
```

Activity where I wish to show the data to the user via list view :

```
package com.example.taskmasterv3;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TaskSummary extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView lvTaskList;
    TextView tvBreak, tvBreakAfterEvery, txt1, txt2, txtwow;
    ArrayList<SummaryList> summaryLists = new ArrayList<>();




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_task_summary);

        lvTaskList = findViewById(R.id.lvTaskList);
        tvBreak = findViewById(R.id.tvBreak);
        tvBreakAfterEvery = findViewById(R.id.tvBreakAfterEvery);
        txt1 = findViewById(R.id.txt1);
        txt2 = findViewById(R.id.txt2);
        txtwow.findViewById(R.id.txtwow);


        int working_hours = getIntent().getIntExtra("working_hours", 1);
        int working_minutes = getIntent().getIntExtra("working_minutes", 0);
        int without_break_hours = getIntent().getIntExtra("without_break_hours", 1);
        int without_break_minutes = getIntent().getIntExtra("without_break_minutes", 0);
        int break_duration = getIntent().getIntExtra("break_duration", 20);
        txt1.setText(working_hours + "");
        txtwow.setText(working_minutes + "");
        txt2.setText(break_duration + "");



        SummaryListAdapter adapter = new SummaryListAdapter(this, summaryLists);
        lvTaskList.setAdapter(adapter);


        

    }
    


}
```

TaskList Class :

```
package com.example.taskmasterv3;

public class SummaryList {

    private String taskName;
    private String priority;
    private String time;
    private int serialNumber;

    public SummaryList(String taskName, String priority, String time, int serialNumber) {
        this.taskName = taskName;
        this.priority = priority;
        this.time = time;
        this.serialNumber = serialNumber;
    }

    public String getTaskName() {
        return taskName;
    }

    public void setTaskName(String taskName) {
        this.taskName = taskName;
    }

    public String getPriority() {
        return priority;
    }

    public void setPriority(String priority) {
        this.priority = priority;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public int getSerialNumber() {
        return serialNumber;
    }

    public void setSerialNumber(int serialNumber) {
        this.serialNumber = serialNumber;
    }
}
```

Adapter Class :

```
package com.example.taskmasterv3;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.room.Insert;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class SummaryListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SummaryList> {


    private final Context context;
    private ArrayList<SummaryList> values;

    public SummaryListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SummaryList> list) {

        super(context, 0, list);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = list;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.task_summary_item, parent, false);
        }

        TextView tvloltaskname = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvloltaskname);
        TextView tvSerNo = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvSerNo);
        ImageView ivlolPri = convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivlolPri);
        ImageView ivlolTime = convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivlolTime);



        // code to connect Room to this


        AppDatabase.databaseWriteExecutor.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {


                tvloltaskname.setText(AppDatabase.getDatabase(context).userDao().getAll().get(position).getSubbuname);
                if (AppDatabase.getDatabase(context).userDao().getAll().get(position).getSubbupri.equals("h")){

                    ivlolPri.setImageResource(R.drawable.priority_high);

                }
                if (AppDatabase.getDatabase(context).userDao().getAll().get(position).getSubbupri.equals("m")){

                    ivlolPri.setImageResource(R.drawable.priority_low);

                }
                if (AppDatabase.getDatabase(context).userDao().getAll().get(position).getSubbupri.equals("l")){

                    ivlolPri.setImageResource(R.drawable.priority_med);

                }
                if (AppDatabase.getDatabase(context).userDao().getAll().get(position).getSubbutime.equals("more")){

                    ivlolTime.setImageResource(R.drawable.time_symbol_more);

                }
                if (AppDatabase.getDatabase(context).userDao().getAll().get(position).getSubbupri.equals("med")){

                    ivlolTime.setImageResource(R.drawable.time_symbol_med);

                }
                if (AppDatabase.getDatabase(context).userDao().getAll().get(position).getSubbupri.equals("less")){

                    ivlolTime.setImageResource(R.drawable.time_symbol_less);

                }
                tvSerNo.setText(position + 1);



            }
        });






        return convertView;
    }

}
```

XML Code for the list item :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSerNo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="1"
        android:textColor="@color/orange_accent"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvloltaskname"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="subtask_name"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivlolPri"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/priority_high" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivlolTime"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/time_symbol_more" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to reload data when come back from another `Activity`, or receive activity result inside `Activity#onActivityResult()` callback, then update the adapter's dataset by using [ArrayAdapter#insert()](https://developer.android.google.cn/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter#insert(T,%20int)) or [ArrayAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged()](https://developer.android.google.cn/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged())

Btw, you are querying database multi times in `SummaryListAdapter#getView()`, this may result in potential performance issue. And `tvSerNo.setText(position + 1);` will trying to load string resource instead of showing the desired serial number, you need to convert that number to `String`.

Comment: I am sorry, but I couldn't properly understand what you're trying to say

Comment: Assuming you have a TaskListActivity and a NewTaskActivity and you are trying to update the list in TaskListActivty after user created a new task in NewTaskActivity.

Comment: Solution 1: Load all items in TaskListActivity's onStart() or onResume() callback to ensure it is reloaded after NewTaskActivity is finished. In this case, you can fill the list view with a new adapter or update existing adpter by replace it's data (you need to add a replaceAll() method to let SummaryListAdapter to support this action)

Comment: Yes I do have such an activity... Okay, I'll try that..

Comment: Solution 2: Keep loading all items in TaskListActivty's onCreate() callback, use Activity#startActivityForResult() to launch NewTaskActivity, after new item saved, deliver it to TaskListActivity by Activity#setResult() in NewTaskActivity. In this case, you'll need to recieve that result item in TaskListActivity's onActivityResult() callback, insert that item into you adapter by calling ArrayAdapter#insert(), and invoke ArrayAdapter#notifyDataSetChaned() if insert() doesn't update the ui automatically.